# Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that the integral $\int^b_a{f(x)dx}$ cannot be 0.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose that
>   $f(x) ≠ 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Show that the integral
>   $\int^b_a{f(x)dx}$ cannot be $0$.

I let $f$ be expressed as a Riemann integral:
Let for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for every partition $P$, it satisfies ||$P$||< $\delta$ we have $|S(f,P) -L| < \epsilon$
Also, maybe more straightforward to show the function has no maximal or minimal values?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and does not have a zero, then $f>0$ or $f<0$.

Comment: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ you won't be able to "show the function has no maximal or minimal values", because it does attain its max and min

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, we can suppose that

$\forall x\in [a,b]\;\; f(x)>0$.

$f$ is continuous at the compact $[a,b]$

$$\implies \exists \alpha\in[a,b]\;\; :$$

$$f(\alpha)=\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)>0$$

$$\implies \int_a^bf(x)dx\geq\int_a^bf(\alpha) dx$$

$$\implies \int_a^bf(x)dx\geq f(\alpha)(b-a)>0$$

Comment: Is $m = \min(f)$?